# Aglutinarse context

Tags: verbos

The verb ''aglutinarse" means to unite, come together or gel together from "aglutinar" to stick.
I wonder is it correct in a tourist context ?e.g. "La Alhambra atrae a miles de turistas. Se aglutinan para ver su belleza y majestuosidad."

I checked in the RAE and it does not give such examples. Spanishdict does give " padres y niños se aglutinan en el parque" and "los niños se aglutinan en el salon para jugar juegos de mesa".
Are these more related to something pre_arranged? Tourists,however, can come together at random to form a crowd. Is it suitable or would "agruparse" be better?

Answer (score 2):

The second RAE definition (an example)of the verb "aglutinar" answers the question:

> 2. tr. aunar (‖ juntar o armonizar). Es capaz de aglutinar a la gente más dispar.

<sub>*RAE [aglutinar](https://dle.rae.es/aglutinar)*</sub>

The main difference I see between *agrupar* and *aglutinar* is that the first one can be conscious while the second one is more casual.

Comment: Thanks. Do I take it so that it is acceptable in my example with La Alhambra?

Comment: Yes, it's totally acceptable